# How do I make my Navbar button work when i click it

Tags: javascript, button, tailwind-css, navbar

I tried to create a hamburger button that toggles my navbar on small screen but it doesnt seem to work, when i click the button nothing happens. How can i get the navbar to be displayed horizontally when the screen is big and show just the burger icon ( the three divs enclosed in the button element) when it is small but i also need the button to toggle navbar off and on ( hidden and block). where are my wrong?

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';


const NavBar = () => {
  const [navState, setNavState] = useState(false);

  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='navbar w-full h-fit text-gray-700 bg-white shadow-lg p-3 md:justify-around  md:flex-row flex-col md:items-center flex fixed z-10 opacity-90'>
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center align-middle'>
        <div>
          <Link href='/'>
            <Image
              src='/Images/BIK.svg'
              width={50}
              height={50}
              alt='Logo'
              className='hover:drop-shadow-xl rounded-full'
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className='md:hidden'>
          {/* Navbar hamburger */}
          <button className='bg-gray-200' onClick={()=>setNavState(!navState)}>
            <div className='w-[20] h-[3] bg-black hover:shadow-xl '></div>
            <div className='w-[20] h-[3] bg-black my-1 hover:shadow-xl'></div>
            <div className='w-[20] h-[3] bg-black hover:shadow-2xl'></div>
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>
        {navState &&
        (<ul className={'md:grid grid-cols-5 gap-1 md:gap-10 justify-between md:w-[600] items-center box-border pl-5'}>
          <li>
            <button className='listlink'>Home</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button className='listlink'><Link href="/about">About</Link></button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button className='listlink'>Projects</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button className='listlink'>Skills</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button className='listlink'>Contact</button>
          </li>
        </ul>)}
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```